# How to create a Jquery shortcut to an eventHandler?

Tags: jquery, events

I would like to create a function like .onmouseover(). Not the functionality but the way the event is bind to an element. I could use .on('ringing',function(){do something}); But I would like to create a .ringing(function(do something)); function. How can I do something like this?

I tried:

```
(function( $ ){
   $.fn.ringing = function(f) {
      $(this).on('ringing',f);
      return this;
   }; 
})( jQuery );

$('body').ringing(function(){
    $(this).css('backgroundColor','blue');
})
```

The ringing event is triggered by something I get from a websocket.

Any help would be great!

Kind Regards,

Comment: What's wrong with just `on('ringing', fn)` and `trigger('ringing')`? This seems a little redundant given you're writing a plugin to save you 5 characters.

Comment: I`m trying to write a libary that users can use. So it is easier to say oh just call the ringing function and when ever there is a ringing event your call back is fired. Otherwise I have to explain jquery....

Answer (score 0):

If I am not mistaken, I think you're trying to achieve the following:

```
// Function definition
$.fn.ringing = function ()
{
    this.css('backgroundColor', 'blue');

    return this;
};

// Call the function like so:
$("body").ringing();
```

Comment: No this is workling... I need to add an eventHandler to (in this case) the body.....